# Why can't UE4 find the implementation of createAgoraRtcEngine?

Tags: agora.io

I am making an Android app in Unreal Engine4.
I want to apply Agora to the Android app.

https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/start_live_android?platform=Android
I applied Agora in the way it is here.

However, if you use createAgoraRtcEngine, it will not build.

[image]

I don't know why the compiler can't find the implementation of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agora's Unreal plugin is currently only supporting PC and Mac development/builds.

There are plans in the future to support Android/iOS, however the Agora Unreal plugin beta was recently launched 04/06/2020.

Here are some links to the repos if you would like to try and get started on PC or Mac!
Otherwise, you are totally able to use Agora SDK on Android, just not with Unreal - *yet*.

[Blueprints Quickstart Repo](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Unreal-SDK-Blueprint)

[C++ Quickstart Repo](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Unreal-SDK-CPP)

If you - and anyone reading this - would like to get started with Agora in the Unreal Engine, we have a community program called [Agora Allstars](https://community.agora.io/) that recognizes creativity, and includes a rewards program for completing the Unreal beta!

Answer (score 0):

FYI - this project says it supports Android now.

https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Unreal-SDK-Blueprint

I, personally, have not tried it yet though.

There is also a C++ equivalent but the documentation does not say it supports Android.
https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Unreal-SDK-CPP